# Recorrer filas de Grid

Tags: c#, datagrid

Estoy tratando de recorrer las filas de una datagrid para que se vayan insertando en la tabla a la BD, lo que sucede es que solo inserta la primera linea
cuando hace la iteracion vuelve a insertar esa misma y asi sucesivamente, no baja a la siguiente, cual es el problema?

```
  foreach (DataGridViewRow item in datagrid.Rows)
                    {

                        for (int i = 1; i < datagrid.Rows.Count-1; i++)
                        {

                            for (int j = 0; j < datagrid.Rows[i].Cells.Count; j++)
                            {
                                comando.Parameters.Clear();

                                float min = 0;
                                float.TryParse(item.Cells[2].Value.ToString(), out min);

                                float max = 0;
                                float.TryParse(item.Cells[4].Value.ToString(), out max);

                                comando.Parameters.Add(":ID", Convert.ToInt32(id));
                                comando.Parameters.Add(":DESCRIPTION", item.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
                                comando.Parameters.Add(":CATEGORY", item.Cells[5].Value.ToString());

                                comando.Parameters.Add(":MIN", min);
                                comando.Parameters.Add(":MAX", max);

                                comando.Parameters.Add(":AREA", item.Cells[3].Value.ToString());
                                comando.Parameters.Add(":RESULT", item.Cells[6].Value.ToString());
                                comando.Parameters.Add(":STATUS", Convert.ToDecimal(item.Cells[7].Value.ToString()));
                                comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Si seguis tu codigo vas a ver que sobra un for. Estas pasando por las filas dos veces, una en el foreach y otra en el rows. Y el otro for por columnas tampoco tiene sentido, si adentro estas recorriendo las columnas manualmente?

Comment: el de la j tampoco iria.. para que queres ir columna por columna si alli adentro estas llendo a todas directamente? o sea.. j no lo usas nunca...

Comment: Entonces que es lo que necesito para que recorra todas las filas porque, si hace el insert varias veces pero solo de la primera,

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que iteras dos veces las `Rows` cuando usas

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow item in datagrid.Rows)
```

y luego

```
for (int i = 1; i < datagrid.Rows.Count-1; i++)
```

Deberia ser

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow item in datagrid.Rows)
{
    comando.Parameters.Clear();

    float min = 0;
    float.TryParse(item.Cells[2].Value.ToString(), out min);

    float max = 0;
    float.TryParse(item.Cells[4].Value.ToString(), out max);

    comando.Parameters.Add(":ID", Convert.ToInt32(id));
    comando.Parameters.Add(":DESCRIPTION", item.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
    comando.Parameters.Add(":CATEGORY", item.Cells[5].Value.ToString());

    comando.Parameters.Add(":MIN", min);
    comando.Parameters.Add(":MAX", max);

    comando.Parameters.Add(":AREA", item.Cells[3].Value.ToString());
    comando.Parameters.Add(":RESULT", item.Cells[6].Value.ToString());
    comando.Parameters.Add(":STATUS", Convert.ToDecimal(item.Cells[7].Value.ToString()));

    comando.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
```

asi solo iteras las rows y tomas los datos de las columnas

Comment: Pero esto es exactamente lo que tengo yo, y asi solo hace el insert de la primera fila varias veces :/

Comment: compara nuevamente el codigo y veras que tu tienes 1 foreach y 2 for, yo solo puse un unico foreach

Comment: Al ver el mensaje del catch die que hay un objeto en blanco y  es que la ultima celda la 7 no tiene nada, hay algo que pueda hacer que cuando una celda este en blanco ponga un 0 por default?

Comment: usa un condicional  algo asi: comando.Parameters.Add(":STATUS", int cellnull = item.Cells[7].Value.ToString() == NULL) ? 0 :  Convert.ToDecimal(item.Cells[7].Value.ToString())); no lo prove pero modificalo

Comment: estas usando el TryParse() para valores numericos, no entiendo porque pasa por el catch. No necesitas definir nada con default en cero porque esto ya lo haces